# Is Ax=b always possible and with unique solution if A is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A is a $n$x$n$ matrix, $x$ is a vector with $n$ components and $b$ is a vector with $n$ components. $Ax=b$ is possible with unique solution iff $A^-1$ exists?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if $A$ is invertible then $$AX=B \iff X=A^{-1}B$$ and the solution is unique.

Comment: That's what I tought. But the text book solution says it's false. Therefore, it implies there exists an exception

Comment: @Daniel The book is wrong. This answer proves one implication. The other one is also true: if $A$ is not invertible, then either the equation doesn't have a solution or the solution is not unique.

Comment: For reference, this is part (6) of the invertible matrix theorem as stated here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html